Refactoring Agreement Status Logic: Applying SOLID Principles and Separating Logging/Auditing with Decorators
I have some production code that contains a lot of repetition and mixes business logic with auditing and logging. I've made two attempts at refactoring it, primarily using decorators. I'd like to get feedback on what’s not ideal and what could be improved in these approaches.
The original code
using SomeNamespace.Commons;
using SomeNamespace.Domain.Enums;
using SomeNamespace.Domain.Repositories;
using SomeNamespace.Faktoring.Core.Date;
using SomeNamespace.Faktoring.Domain.Entities;
using SomeNamespace.Faktoring.Domain.Enums;
using SomeNamespace.Faktoring.Domain.Repositories.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog;
using System;

namespace SomeNamespace.Core.Faktoring.Implementation
{
    public class FaktoringAgreementStatusService : IFaktoringAgreementStatusService
    {
        private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _netLogger = NetCoreLogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        private readonly IFaktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository _faktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository;
        private readonly IAgreementStatusRepository _agreementStatusRepository;
        private readonly IFaktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository _faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository;
        private readonly IDateService _dateService;

        public FaktoringAgreementStatusService(
            IFaktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository faktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository,
            IAgreementStatusRepository agreementStatusRepository,
            IFaktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository,
            IDateService dateService)
        {
            _faktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository = faktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository;
            _agreementStatusRepository = agreementStatusRepository;
            _faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository = faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository;
            _dateService = dateService;
        }

        public void SetFaktoringStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, AgreementStatusId status, string comment)
        {
            switch (status)
            {
                case AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted:
                    ChangeToStarted(agreement, comment);
                    break;
                case AgreementStatusId.CanceledAfterWLVerification:
                    ChangeToCanceledAfterWLVerification(agreement, comment);
                    break;
                case AgreementStatusId.CanceledAfterFailedFinancing:
                    ChangeToCanceledAfterFailedFinancing(agreement, comment);
                    break;
                case AgreementStatusId.Paid:
                    ChangeToPaid(agreement, comment);
                    break;
                case AgreementStatusId.CanceledNoInitialFee:
                    ChangeToCanceledNoInitialFee(agreement, comment);
                    break;
                case AgreementStatusId.CanceledBeforeFinancing:
                    ChangeToCanceledBeforeFinancing(agreement, comment);
                    break;
                case AgreementStatusId.CanceledReturnTransfer:
                    ChangeToCanceledReturnTransfer(agreement, comment);
                    break;
                case AgreementStatusId.CanceledAdvancePaymentAmountMismatch:
                    ChangeToCanceledAdvancePaymentAmountMismatch(agreement, comment);
                    break;
                default:
                    string errorMessage = $"Status umowy '{status}' nie jest dostępnym statusem faktoringu";
                    Logger.Error(errorMessage);
                    _netLogger.LogError(errorMessage);
                    throw new Exception(errorMessage);
            }
        }

        private void ChangeToStarted(FaktoringAgreement agreement, string comment)
        {
            if (agreement.AgreementStatus.Id != (long)AgreementStatusId.Agreement
                && agreement.AgreementStatus.Id != (long)AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted)
            {
                Logger.Error("Faktoring nie może zmienić statusu na 'Uruchomiona', dopóki nie jest zawarta umowa");
                _netLogger.LogError("Faktoring nie może zmienić statusu na 'Uruchomiona', dopóki nie jest zawarta umowa");
                return;
            }

            ChangeStatusAndLogInformation(agreement, (long)AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted, comment);
        }

        private void ChangeToCanceledAfterWLVerification(FaktoringAgreement agreement, string comment)
        {
            if (agreement.AgreementStatus.Id != (long)AgreementStatusId.Agreement)
            {
                Logger.Error("Faktoring nie może zmienić statusu na 'Unieważniona - weryfikacja WL', dopóki nie jest zawarta umowa");
                _netLogger.LogError("Faktoring nie może zmienić statusu na 'Unieważniona - weryfikacja WL', dopóki nie jest zawarta umowa");
                return;
            }

            ChangeStatusAndLogInformation(agreement, (long)AgreementStatusId.CanceledAfterWLVerification, comment, (long)InitialFeeStatusId.AgreementTerminated);
        }

        private void ChangeToCanceledNoInitialFee(FaktoringAgreement agreement, string comment)
        {
            if (agreement.AgreementStatus.Id != (long)AgreementStatusId.Agreement)
            {
                Logger.Error("Faktoring nie może zmienić statusu na 'Unieważniona - brak opłaty wstepnej', dopóki nie jest zawarta umowa");
                _netLogger.LogError("Faktoring nie może zmienić statusu na 'Unieważniona - brak opłaty wstepnej', dopóki nie jest zawarta umowa");
                return;
            }

            ResetInitialFeeToPay(agreement);
            ChangeStatusAndLogInformation(agreement, (long)AgreementStatusId.CanceledNoInitialFee, comment, (long)InitialFeeStatusId.AgreementTerminated);
        }


        private void ChangeStatusAndLogInformation(FaktoringAgreement agreement, long statusId, string comment, long? initialFeeStatus = null)
        {
            if (initialFeeStatus.HasValue)
            {
                agreement.InitialFeeStatus = _faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository.LazyGet(initialFeeStatus.Value);
            }

            var date = _dateService.GetNextDateTimeOffset(agreement.FaktoringRegistrationState.Id) ?? DateTimeOffset.Now;

            agreement.AgreementStatus = _agreementStatusRepository.LazyGet(statusId);
            agreement.LastStatusChangedDate = date;
            _faktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository.LogFaktoringAgreementStatusChange(agreement, date, comment);
        }

        private void ResetInitialFeeToPay(FaktoringAgreement agreement)
        {
            agreement.InitialFeeToPay = 0;
        }
    }
}

I didn't include all the method implementations from the switch statement, as they were mostly repetitions of three unique cases. Each case involves pre-validation followed by slightly different operations. Here’s a summary of what they do:

Change the agreement status and audit the change to IFaktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository (the order can vary).
Reset the initial fee, change the agreement status, change the initial fee status (to "terminated"), and audit the change (order can vary).
Change the agreement status, change the initial fee status (to "terminated"), and audit the change (order can vary).

I have two approaches to refactor this.
The refactored code - first approach
I used strategies with decorators to separate concerns. Below are examples of the implementations:
 public interface IAgreementStatusStrategy
 {
     void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, string comment);
 }

 public class ChangeToStartedStrategy : IAgreementStatusStrategy
 {
     private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _agreementStatus;

     public ChangeToStartedStrategy()
     {
          var changeAgreementStatus = new ChangeAgreementStatus(default(IAgreementStatusRepository), default(IDateService));
          var changeAgreementStatusWithLogging = new ChangeAgreementStatusWithLogging(changeAgreementStatus);
          var changeStatusWithAudit = new ChangStatusWithAudit(changeAgreementStatusWithLogging, null);

          _agreementStatus = changeStatusWithAudit;
      }

      public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, string comment)
      {
          _agreementStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, (long)AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted, comment);
      }
  }

 public class ChangeToCanceledAfterFailedFinancingStrategy : IAgreementStatusStrategy
 {
     private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _agreementStatus;

     public ChangeToCanceledAfterFailedFinancingStrategy()
     {
         var changeAgreementStatus = new ChangeAgreementStatus(default(IAgreementStatusRepository), default(IDateService));
         var changeAgreementStatusWithLogging = new ChangeAgreementStatusWithLogging(changeAgreementStatus);
         var changeStatusTerminateInitialFee = new ChangeStatusTerminateInitialFee(default(IFaktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository), changeAgreementStatusWithLogging);
         var changeStatusWithAudit = new ChangStatusWithAudit(changeStatusTerminateInitialFee, null);

         _agreementStatus = changeStatusWithAudit;
     }

     public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, string comment)
     {
         _agreementStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, (long)AgreementStatusId.CanceledAfterFailedFinancing, comment);
     }
 }

public class ChangeToCanceledNoInitialFeeStrategy : IAgreementStatusStrategy
{
    private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _agreementStatus;

    public ChangeToCanceledNoInitialFeeStrategy()
    {
        var changeAgreementStatus = new ChangeAgreementStatus(default(IAgreementStatusRepository), default(IDateService));
        var changeAgreementStatusWithLogging = new ChangeAgreementStatusWithLogging(changeAgreementStatus);
        var changeStatusResetInitialFee = new ChangeStatusResetInitialFee(changeAgreementStatusWithLogging);
        var changeStatusTerminateInitialFee = new ChangeStatusTerminateInitialFee(default(IFaktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository), changeStatusResetInitialFee);
        var changeStatusWithAudit = new ChangStatusWithAudit(changeStatusTerminateInitialFee, null);

        _agreementStatus = changeStatusWithAudit;
    }

    public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, string comment)
    {
        _agreementStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, (long)AgreementStatusId.CanceledNoInitialFee, comment);
    }
}

Base implementation and decorators:
public interface IChangeAgreementStatus
{
    void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, long statusId, string comment);
}

 public class ChangeAgreementStatus : IChangeAgreementStatus
 {
     private readonly IAgreementStatusRepository _agreementStatusRepository;
     private readonly IDateService _dateService;

     public ChangeAgreementStatus(IAgreementStatusRepository agreementStatusRepository, IDateService dateService)
     {
         _agreementStatusRepository = agreementStatusRepository;
         _dateService = dateService;
     }

     public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, long statusId, string comment)
     {
         var newStatus = _agreementStatusRepository.LazyGet(statusId);
         var date = _dateService.GetNextDateTimeOffset(agreement.FaktoringRegistrationState.Id) ?? DateTimeOffset.Now;
         agreement.ChangeStatus(newStatus, date);
     }
 }

public class ChangStatusWithAudit : IChangeAgreementStatus
{
    private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _changeAgreementStatus;
    private readonly IFaktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository _faktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository;

    public ChangStatusWithAudit(IChangeAgreementStatus changeAgreementStatus,
        IFaktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository faktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository)
    {
        _changeAgreementStatus = changeAgreementStatus;
        _faktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository = faktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository;
    }

    public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, long statusId, string comment)
    {
        _changeAgreementStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, statusId, comment);
        _faktoringAgreementStatusChangeRepository.LogFaktoringAgreementStatusChange(agreement, agreement.LastStatusChangedDate!.Value, comment);
    }
}

public class ChangeStatusResetInitialFee : IChangeAgreementStatus
{
    private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _changeAgreementStatus;

    public ChangeStatusResetInitialFee(IChangeAgreementStatus changeAgreementStatus)
    {
        _changeAgreementStatus = changeAgreementStatus;
    }

    public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, long statusId, string comment)
    {
       ResetInitialFeeToPay(agreement);
       _changeAgreementStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, statusId, comment);
    }

    public void ResetInitialFeeToPay(FaktoringAgreement agreement)
    {
        agreement.InitialFeeToPay = 0;
    }
}

public class ChangeStatusTerminateInitialFee : IChangeAgreementStatus
{
    private readonly IFaktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository _faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository;
    private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _changeAgreementStatus;

    public ChangeStatusTerminateInitialFee(IFaktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository, IChangeAgreementStatus changeAgreementStatus)
    {
        _faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository = faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository;
        _changeAgreementStatus = changeAgreementStatus;
    }

    public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, long statusId, string comment)
    {
        _changeAgreementStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, statusId, comment);

      agreement.ChangeInitialFeeStatus(_faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository.LazyGet((long)InitialFeeStatusId.AgreementTerminated));
    }
}


public class ChangeAgreementStatusWithLogging : IChangeAgreementStatus
{
  private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _changeAgreementStatus;
  private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
  private readonly Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _netLogger = NetCoreLogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
  public ChangeAgreementStatusWithLogging(IChangeAgreementStatus changeAgreementStatus)
  {
      _changeAgreementStatus = changeAgreementStatus;
  }

  public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, long statusId, string comment)
  {
      try
      {
          _changeAgreementStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, statusId, comment);
      }
      catch (FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException e)
      {
          Log(e.Message);
          throw;
      }
  }

  public void Log(string message)
  {
      Logger.Error(message);
      _netLogger.LogError(message);
  }
}

As you can see, I added a new domain exception and moved some logic into the entity, making it a more "rich model" approach:
 public class FaktoringAgreement : Entity, IVersionable
 {
     // properties
 
     public void ChangeStatus(AgreementStatusShared newStatus, DateTimeOffset date)
     {
         var newStatusId = (AgreementStatusId)newStatus.Id;
         var currentStatus = (AgreementStatusId)AgreementStatus.Id;

         switch (newStatusId)
         {
             case AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted when currentStatus != AgreementStatusId.Agreement && currentStatus != AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted:
                 throw FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException.NoAgreement(newStatus.Name);
             case AgreementStatusId.CanceledAfterFailedFinancing when currentStatus != AgreementStatusId.Agreement:
                 throw FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException.NoAgreement(newStatus.Name);
             case AgreementStatusId.Paid when currentStatus != AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted:
                 throw FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException.AgreementNotStarted(newStatus.Name);
             case AgreementStatusId.CanceledNoInitialFee when currentStatus != AgreementStatusId.Agreement:
                 throw FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException.NoAgreement(newStatus.Name);
             case AgreementStatusId.CanceledBeforeFinancing when currentStatus != AgreementStatusId.Agreement:
                 throw FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException.NoAgreement(newStatus.Name);
             case AgreementStatusId.CanceledReturnTransfer when currentStatus != AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted:
                 throw FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException.AgreementNotStarted(newStatus.Name);
             case AgreementStatusId.CanceledAdvancePaymentAmountMismatch when currentStatus != AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted:
                 throw FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException.AgreementNotStarted(newStatus.Name);
         }

         this.AgreementStatus = newStatus;
         this.LastStatusChangedDate = date;
     }

     public void ChangeInitialFeeStatus(FaktoringInitialFeeStatus initialFeeStatus)
     {
          InitialFeeStatus = initialFeeStatus;
     }
     
     public void ResetInitialFee()
     {
          InitialFeeToPay = 0;
     }
 }

Domain exception:
   public class FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException : Exception
   {
       public static FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException NoAgreement(string name)
       {
           return new FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException($"Faktoring nie może zmienić statusu na '{name}', dopóki nie jest zawarta umowa");
       }

       public static FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException AgreementNotStarted(string name)
       {
           return new FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException($"Faktoring nie może zmienić statusu na '{name}',  dopóki nie jest uruchomiona");
       }


       public FaktoringStatusChangeDomainException(string message) : base(message)
       {
       }
   }

I think this approach is much cleaner and separates cross-cutting concerns from business logic. However, I dislike the complex wiring of the decorators, and I feel that separating the initial fee logic into decorators might be over-engineering. This led me to consider a second approach, which is similar but doesn't use decorators for resetting the initial fee and its status.
The refactored code - second approach
In this approach, I simplified the handling of initial fees. Here are the strategy implementations:
  public class ChangeToStartedStrategy : IAgreementStatusStrategy
  {
      private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _agreementStatus;

      public ChangeToStartedStrategy()
      {
          var changeAgreementStatus = new ChangeAgreementStatus(default(IAgreementStatusRepository), default(IDateService));
          var changeAgreementStatusWithLogging = new ChangeAgreementStatusWithLogging(changeAgreementStatus);
          var changeStatusWithAudit = new ChangStatusWithAudit(changeAgreementStatusWithLogging, null);

          _agreementStatus = changeStatusWithAudit;
      }

      public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, string comment)
      {
          _agreementStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, (long)AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted, comment);
      }
  }

  public class ChangeToCanceledAfterFailedFinancingStrategy : IAgreementStatusStrategy
  {
      private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _agreementStatus;
      private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _initialFeeChangeStatus;

      public ChangeToCanceledAfterFailedFinancingStrategy()
      {
          var changeAgreementStatus = new ChangeAgreementStatus(default(IAgreementStatusRepository), default(IDateService));
          // Create the decorators in the desired order
          var changeAgreementStatusWithLogging = new ChangeAgreementStatusWithLogging(changeAgreementStatus);
          var changeStatusWithAudit = new ChangStatusWithAudit(changeAgreementStatusWithLogging, null);

          _agreementStatus = changeStatusWithAudit;
          _initialFeeChangeStatus = new ChangeInitialFeeStatus(null);
      }

      public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, string comment)
      {
          _agreementStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, (long)AgreementStatusId.CanceledAfterFailedFinancing, comment);
          _initialFeeChangeStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, (long) InitialFeeStatusId.AgreementTerminated, comment);
      }
  }

  public class ChangeToCanceledNoInitialFeeStrategy : IAgreementStatusStrategy
  {
      private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _agreementStatus;
      private readonly IChangeAgreementStatus _initialFeeChangeStatus;

      public ChangeToCanceledNoInitialFeeStrategy()
      {
          var changeAgreementStatus = new ChangeAgreementStatus(default(IAgreementStatusRepository), default(IDateService));
          // Create the decorators in the desired order
          var changeAgreementStatusWithLogging = new ChangeAgreementStatusWithLogging(changeAgreementStatus);
          var changeStatusWithAudit = new ChangStatusWithAudit(changeAgreementStatusWithLogging, null);

          _agreementStatus = changeStatusWithAudit;
          _initialFeeChangeStatus = new ChangeInitialFeeStatus(null);
      }

      public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, string comment)
      {
          _agreementStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, (long)AgreementStatusId.CanceledNoInitialFee, comment);
          agreement.ResetInitialFee();
          _initialFeeChangeStatus.ChangeStatus(agreement, (long) InitialFeeStatusId.AgreementTerminated, comment);
      }
  }



Now, ChangeInitialFeeStatus has changed:
public class ChangeInitialFeeStatus : IChangeAgreementStatus
{
    private readonly IFaktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository _faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository;

    public ChangeInitialFeeStatus(IFaktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository)
    {
        _faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository = faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository;
    }

    public void ChangeStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, long statusId, string comment)
    {
        agreement.ChangeInitialFeeStatus(_faktoringInitialFeeStatusRepository.LazyGet(statusId));
    }
}

I prefer this approach because it makes the business logic clearer, and I have more flexibility in setting any status for InitialFee, not just "terminated."
Summary
In both approaches, the client code looks like this:
  public class FaktoringAgreementStatusService : IFaktoringAgreementStatusService
  {
      private readonly IAgreementStatusStrategyFactory _strategyFactory;

      public FaktoringAgreementStatusService(IAgreementStatusStrategyFactory strategyFactory)
      {
          _strategyFactory = strategyFactory;
      }

      public void SetFaktoringStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, AgreementStatusId status, string comment)
      {
          var strategy = _strategyFactory.GetStrategy(status);
          strategy.ChangeStatus(agreement, comment);
      }
  }

Regarding the instantiation of IChangeAgreementStatus, this is just an example. In the final step, I would add the appropriate dependency injection code using Castle Windsor.

Did you really manage to get multiple classes into a single file? Where are the using statements. This does not appear to be the code as it would be in the program.

Why do you need using statements? Of course they should be in seperate files this is just example of refactor. I have productions usings I should have to anonymize them.  In all code examples for solid or tutorials usings are not showed, I don't understand why this is a problem. My question is about patterns and refactoring not whole code review.

Ok I added the using statements for the original code. All refactored classes uses the same using but i did not seperate them because yes they are in one file, because it was easier for me to see the whole thing when I refactor. As final cleanup i split them with resharper in few seconds.

There are parts in the original code missing, and also parts just don't make sense to me.

Why agreement.AgreementStatus.Id != (long)AgreementStatusId.Agreement is not checked before going to the switch statement? as from the code, it seems it's the first condition to be checked.
AgreementStatusId seems an enum, and if that's true, then why does the switch throws an exception on the default case? as the default will never be called since the method argument already have a safeguard for of that.
Why do you call two loggers ? shouldn't you just use one logger with all classes? and if you have multiple loggers in your project, shouldn't you just create a wrapper class that will handle both loggers, and register it to the DI container, and use that class instead of using two loggers. Plus all logging messages seems to be identical for both loggers !.

I don't speak polish, but from google translator, it seems all logging texts are the same, and the only different between them is the status, which is mentioned in polish.
If that the case you could refactor SetFaktoringStatus to something like this :
public void SetFaktoringStatus(FaktoringAgreement agreement, AgreementStatusId status, string comment)
{
    if(agreement.AgreementStatus.Id != (long)AgreementStatusId.Agreement)
    {
        Logger.Error($"Faktoring nie może zmienić statusu na {status}, dopóki nie jest zawarta umowa");
        _netLogger.LogError($"Faktoring nie może zmienić statusu na {status}, dopóki nie jest zawarta umowa");  
        return;
    }
    
    long? initialFeeStatus = null;

    switch (status)
    {
        case AgreementStatusId.CanceledAfterWLVerification:
            initialFeeStatus = (long)InitialFeeStatusId.AgreementTerminated;
            break;
        case AgreementStatusId.CanceledNoInitialFee:
            agreement.InitialFeeToPay = 0;
            initialFeeStatus = (long)InitialFeeStatusId.AgreementTerminated;
            break;
    }
    
    ChangeStatusAndLogInformation(agreement, (long)status, comment, initialFeeStatus);
}

Now, you can remove all related methods within the class, and if there is special cases, you can just add them into the switch to handle them.

-Two loggers, because our maintenance team decided to log this to db and azure app insights. Don't ask my why they did not decied to wrap this to one log method.

When someone calls SetFakturatkaStatus with new status they should know that they have to handle it consciously that's why exception is throwed.

AgreemenStatus, yes this is enum, but why you omitted "(long)AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted" check? It is neeed for AgreementStarted
if (agreement.AgreementStatus.Id != (long)AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted){}

And last question. Can you tell me why you did not answer for my propositions and attempt to SOLID? Is it overengineering for you?

I have omitted AgreementStarted condition, along with all other methods and cases, because of redundancy. There is no actual logic that needed to have that condition nor the methods; as I've demonstrated in my answer.  wither you added AgreementStarted condition or removed it, it will not change the current code flow, since it will be always false (because of the switch case`) - (for the current code scope).

since I my reviews are related to the current code scope (that is included in the question), for your SOLID propositions , it's overengineering at least for this scope, but if you have a different angle of view that might be applicable in a wider scope, then that would need to include that in your question, along with any missing code area that was not mentioned.

Ah I chosen wrong examples :/ In this case it can't be omitted. Cause you can't change to paid if agreement is not started yet. Next time I should provide some small github example repo...

private void ChangeToPaid(FakturatkaAgreement agreement, string comment)
{
if (agreement.AgreementStatus.Id != (long)AgreementStatusId.AgreementStarted)
{
Logger.Error("Fakturatka nie może zmienić statusu na 'Spłacona', dopóki nie jest uruchomiona");
return;
}
 ChangeStatusAndLogInformation(agreement, (long)AgreementStatusId.Paid, comment);

}

